# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, signalr

i am trying to install SignalR on my Website ( Not a Web application ) (using visual studio 2012 ), when i created my website ( File--New Website ) i selected .net 4.5, my problem is when i am installing SignalR with Nuget Package this error happens

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

on also in my web.config line  `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>` says

> the targetFramework attribute is not allowed.

and my web.config is

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="KutSocialNetworkConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=KutSocialNetwork;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="path" value=""/>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode"
           verb="*"
           path="UrlRouting.axd"
           type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: In the properties of the web project (csproj), what is the targeted framework?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So it was Easy , i downloaded directly from `Nuget` , and also delete my `webconfig` and created a new One